# Bootstrap card whose image image is top/left, depending on column breakpoint?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

Most Bootstrap 4 `card`s with images have either a `.card-img-top` or an image that goes somewhere else, like left, using additional/custom code.

Is there such thing as code for a single card whose image may be either at top of body or at left of body, depending on width?

See below, my current two different card types...

- Top one is more standard with .card-img-top applied.
- However, in certain scenarios on my site, I will want a more horizontal approach, with image on the left, achieved not with `.card-img-top` but with two additional columns, side-by-side. You also see this in the image.

[image]

Right now, I have had to write separate code to do this - one card type for vertical, the other for horizontal.

So I am curious - **can I have a card whose image is either on top or on left depending on the size of the column containing it?**

I'm trying to think it through, though...
At browser `xs` and `sm`, all columns would be 12 and vertical cards required.
But at browser `md` and `lg`, column widths will be varied according to mark-up needs as seen in the image.

Is this something that can be achieved using single-card code, or is there logic that is more complex than just this?

FYI...

1. Here is the code for my vertical cards...

   **Interviews**

   ```
   <!-- column -->
   <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-2">
       <!-- Card -->
       <div class="card rounded-0 w-100 bg-white shadow-sm">
           <a href="http://www.thedrum.com/news/2016/11/29/something-going-have-change-quickly-fts-elli-papadaki-programmatic-transparency">
                           <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/article_drum.jpeg" class="card-img-top img-fluid rounded-0"><!-- had w-100 -->
                         </a>
           <div class="card-body pb-2">
               <h6 class="card-title"><a href="http://www.thedrum.com/news/2016/11/29/something-going-have-change-quickly-fts-elli-papadaki-programmatic-transparency" class="text-dark">‘Something is going to have to change quickly,’ FT’s Elli Papadaki on programmatic transparency</a></h6>
           </div>
           <div class="card-footer bg-white text-muted small pt-0 border-top-0 px-3">
                         <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/fav_drum.png" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                         <span class="ml-1"><a href="/source/the-drum/" class="text-muted">The Drum</a></span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <!-- Card -->
   </div>
   <!-- column -->


   <!-- column -->
   <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-2">
       <!-- Card -->
       <div class="card rounded-0 w-100 bg-white shadow-sm">
           <a href="https://gigaom.com/2012/02/28/419-interview-ft-ceo-denies-sale-and-braves-strike-ahead-of-social-launch/">
                           <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/john-ridding-o.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid rounded-0"><!-- had w-100 -->
                         </a>
           <div class="card-body pb-2">
               <h6 class="card-title"><a href="https://gigaom.com/2012/02/28/419-interview-ft-ceo-denies-sale-and-braves-strike-ahead-of-social-launch/" class="text-dark">Interview: FT CEO Denies Sale And Braves Strike Ahead Of Social Launch</a></h6>
           </div>
           <div class="card-footer bg-white text-muted small pt-0 border-top-0 px-3">
                         <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/favicon_pc.gif" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                         <span class="ml-1"><a href="/source/paidcontent/" class="text-muted">paidContent</a></span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <!-- Card -->
   </div>
   <!-- column -->


   <!-- column -->
   <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-2">
       <!-- Card -->
       <div class="card rounded-0 w-100 bg-white shadow-sm">
           <a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/08/08/419-interview-digitals-second-age-begins-now-ft-ceo-says/">
                           <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/john-ridding-o.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid rounded-0"><!-- had w-100 -->
                         </a>
           <div class="card-body pb-2">
               <h6 class="card-title"><a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/08/08/419-interview-digitals-second-age-begins-now-ft-ceo-says/" class="text-dark">Interview: Digital’s Second Age Begins Now, FT CEO Says</a></h6>
           </div>
           <div class="card-footer bg-white text-muted small pt-0 border-top-0 px-3">
                         <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://gigaom.com/2011/08/08/419-interview-digitals-second-age-begins-now-ft-ceo-says/" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                         <span class="ml-1"><a href="/source/moconews/" class="text-muted">moconews</a></span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <!-- Card -->
   </div>
   <!-- column -->


   <!-- column -->
   <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-2">
       <!-- Card -->
       <div class="card rounded-0 w-100 bg-white shadow-sm">
           <a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/06/07/419-interview-financial-times-grimshaw-app-stores-are-not-a-panacea/">
                           <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/rob-grimshaw-official-o-640x443.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid rounded-0"><!-- had w-100 -->
                         </a>
           <div class="card-body pb-2">
               <h6 class="card-title"><a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/06/07/419-interview-financial-times-grimshaw-app-stores-are-not-a-panacea/" class="text-dark">Interview: Financial Times’ Grimshaw: ‘App Stores Are Not A Panacea’</a></h6>
           </div>
           <div class="card-footer bg-white text-muted small pt-0 border-top-0 px-3">
                         <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://gigaom.com/2011/06/07/419-interview-financial-times-grimshaw-app-stores-are-not-a-panacea/" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                         <span class="ml-1"><a href="/source/moconews/" class="text-muted">moconews</a></span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <!-- Card -->
   </div>
   <!-- column -->
   ```

2.

And here is the code I'm trying for the horizontal-style cards...

```
<p><strong>Interviews</strong></p>

<div class="row">





<!-- column -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-2">
    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="card rounded-0 bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="http://www.thedrum.com/news/2016/11/29/something-going-have-change-quickly-fts-elli-papadaki-programmatic-transparency">
                                        <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/article_drum.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded-0" style="object-fit:cover"><!-- had w-100 -->
                                      </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 pl-0 py-2">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <h6 class="card-title"><a href="http://www.thedrum.com/news/2016/11/29/something-going-have-change-quickly-fts-elli-papadaki-programmatic-transparency" class="text-dark">‘Something is going to have to change quickly,’ FT’s Elli Papadaki on programmatic transparency</a></h6>
                                              <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/fav_drum.png" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                            <span class="small pl-0 ml-0"><a href="/source/the-drum/" class="text-muted">The Drum</a></span>


                                  </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- Card -->
</div>
<!-- column -->





<!-- column -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-2">
    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="card rounded-0 bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="https://gigaom.com/2012/02/28/419-interview-ft-ceo-denies-sale-and-braves-strike-ahead-of-social-launch/">
                                        <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/john-ridding-o.png" class="img-fluid rounded-0" style="object-fit:cover"><!-- had w-100 -->
                                      </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 pl-0 py-2">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <h6 class="card-title"><a href="https://gigaom.com/2012/02/28/419-interview-ft-ceo-denies-sale-and-braves-strike-ahead-of-social-launch/" class="text-dark">Interview: FT CEO Denies Sale And Braves Strike Ahead Of Social Launch</a></h6>
                                              <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/favicon_pc.gif" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                            <span class="small pl-0 ml-0"><a href="/source/paidcontent/" class="text-muted">paidContent</a></span>




                                  </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- Card -->
</div>
<!-- column -->





<!-- column -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-2">
    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="card rounded-0 bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/08/08/419-interview-digitals-second-age-begins-now-ft-ceo-says/">
                                        <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/john-ridding-o.png" class="img-fluid rounded-0" style="object-fit:cover"><!-- had w-100 -->
                                      </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 pl-0 py-2">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <h6 class="card-title"><a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/08/08/419-interview-digitals-second-age-begins-now-ft-ceo-says/" class="text-dark">Interview: Digital’s Second Age Begins Now, FT CEO Says</a></h6>
                                              <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://gigaom.com/2011/08/08/419-interview-digitals-second-age-begins-now-ft-ceo-says/" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                            <span class="small pl-0 ml-0"><a href="/source/moconews/" class="text-muted">moconews</a></span>





                                  </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- Card -->
</div>
<!-- column -->





<!-- column -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-2">
    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="card rounded-0 bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/06/07/419-interview-financial-times-grimshaw-app-stores-are-not-a-panacea/">
                                        <img src="http://www.example.com/image/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/rob-grimshaw-official-o-640x443.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-0" style="object-fit:cover"><!-- had w-100 -->
                                      </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 pl-0 py-2">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <h6 class="card-title"><a href="https://gigaom.com/2011/06/07/419-interview-financial-times-grimshaw-app-stores-are-not-a-panacea/" class="text-dark">Interview: Financial Times’ Grimshaw: ‘App Stores Are Not A Panacea’</a></h6>
                                              <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://gigaom.com/2011/06/07/419-interview-financial-times-grimshaw-app-stores-are-not-a-panacea/" width="17" class="rounded-circle">
                            <span class="small pl-0 ml-0"><a href="/source/moconews/" class="text-muted">moconews</a></span>





                                  </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- Card -->
</div>
<!-- column -->
          </div>




</div>
```

(I am endeavouring to make the images "cover" style, where they fill the available space.
Images on a vertical card should retain a landscape orientation, images on a horizontal card should be square. NB - there is currently an issue with my horizontal-card code which introduces a border/margin below the left image when the text on the right is longer than it.)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly ( was a long read :) ) , you could make use of the `flex-direction` property.

I made a simple example for you. First, the columns are one after the other ( horizontally ) and the contents inside the same.

Then after a desired breaking point ( 600px ) i made the columns to have a column direction.

You could also play around with bootstrap classes and you might get the same result.

See snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8k5Lm2r/3/)

```css
.col-4 {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-4 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe seem to kind of work. I need to put a `.card` inside the column. And I'm actually unclear about the interplay between `col-*` class and `@media` stuff. ie. My current vertical cards take `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3` so what on earth would I do?